# javascript/jQuery location.href misses mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page that has a number of elements that are slid up on startup. I want to be able to slide down a particular pane based on the hash in the url my code is

```
    if (window.location.hash.length>0){

   var id = window.location.hash;

   if (id.length==7){ //expected hash is 7 chars long (inc #)

    console.log('Comment hash in url, finding link');

    $(id).parents('.details_wrapper').parent().show().find('.details_wrapper').addClass('open').slideDown('slow', function(){ //unhide and slidedown pane
     window.location.href = id;
    });
   }
  }
```

Which sort of works in that the appropriate pane is revealed and slid down, however the window.location.href doesn't seem to be working very well as the window consistently places the page about 800px further down than where the anchor is.

As a possible side note it seems I can't verify the correct href as typing

```
window.location.href='#c83225';
```

into the developer console (Safari) gives an error. It works in the Chrome console though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option to do that is

```
window.location.hash = 'c83225';
```